# Rules: how to display the value of variables?

Tags: rules, debugging

I use the Devel module on Drupal 7 to debug some rules of my site but I can't debug without knowing the value of variables I created.

In the case, I have a loop where I sum different values and at the end of the loop I store that in a second variable that I compare to fixed parameters.

Is there something that can show me every value of the rules variables?

In the default log I have only events but I don't know anything else...
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Two options:

- At admin/config/workflow/rules/settings, set "Show debug information" to "Always."
- In the rule's actions, add the action "Show a message on the site" (under the System group, I believe). Pass it the variable(s) you want to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second method used with php code is very good!